# How can I use MariaDB to pull values from multiple objects from a JSON array?

Tags: mysql, json, mariadb

In MariaDB 10.2.19, I have a table named `forms` with a column `template` which always contains a JSON array of objects. Some of these objects will have properties I want to return: `name` (should always be present), `rule`, and `parameters`. How can I return just these three properties from the entire array, but only for objects on which `rule` is present?

A sample array (formatted for easier viewing):

```
[{
    "label": "Employed?",
    "class": "select",
    "name": "employed",
    "parameters": "Yes",
    "rule": "in"
},
{
    "label": "Breed of dog?",
    "class": "select",
    "name": "breed",
    "parameters": "spaniel, collie, mix",
    "rule": "in"
},
{
    "label": "Number",
    "class": "text",
    "name": "breed"
}]
```

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you had ordinary columns, `NULLable` in some cases, instead of JSON.

Comment: @RickJames Agreed. It would be infinitely easier if the problem did not exist at all, yet it does, so here I am.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL 8.0.4 or later one way is using `JSON_TABLE`:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM foo;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| data                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| [{"name": "employed", "rule": "in", "class": "select", "label": "Employed?", "parameters": "Yes"}, {"name": "breed", "rule": "in", "class": "select", "label": "Breed of dog?", "parameters": "spaniel, collie, mix"}, {"name": "breed", "class": "text", "label": "Number"}] |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> SELECT name, parameters 
         FROM foo,
              JSON_TABLE (
                  foo.data, 
                  "$[*]" COLUMNS (
                      name VARCHAR(100) PATH "$.name",
                      rule VARCHAR(100) PATH "$.rule",
                      parameters VARCHAR(100) PATH "$.parameters")
              ) AS t
       WHERE rule IS NOT NULL;
+----------+----------------------+
| name     | parameters           |
+----------+----------------------+
| employed | Yes                  |
| breed    | spaniel, collie, mix |
+----------+----------------------+
2 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html

Comment: This would be perfect for my dilemma. Unfortunately, the database is on MariaDB 10.2.19 which does not support JSON_TABLE(). My question did not reflect this, so I have updated it accordingly.

Comment: Well, both systems are quite different meanwhile, mind that MariaDB also has no true JSON datatype, but only an alias to BLOB, thus not as efficient access and replication. Probably you might do something in a stored procedure using `JSON_SEARCH` which gives paths to all `rule`s then some string processing and `JSON_EXTRACT` in a loop (Disclaimer: I work for Oracle's MySQL Team, opinions however are my own)

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using a dedicated `numbers_table` table:

```
SELECT
    JSON_VALUE(f.template,CONCAT('$[',n.number,'].name')) AS `name`,
    JSON_VALUE(f.template,CONCAT('$[',n.number,'].rule')) AS `rule`,
    JSON_VALUE(f.template,CONCAT('$[',n.number,'].parameters')) AS `parameters`
FROM forms AS f
JOIN numbers_table AS n
WHERE
    n.number < JSON_LENGTH(f.template) AND
    JSON_VALUE(f.template,CONCAT('$[',n.number,'].rule')) IS NOT NULL;
```

The `numbers_table` table contains a single column called `number` which starts at `0` and can be as long as your use cases require (I have 1000 values `0` to `999`). It is very useful for extracting each element of a `JSON_ARRAY` field into its own row.

The first `WHERE` condition makes sure we only use as many numbers as there are elements in the `JSON_ARRAY` (`template` in your case).

The second `WHERE` condition eliminates the ones that don't have a `rule` as per your use case.